# Getting velocity error "unable to find resource 'error.vm' in any resource loader."

Tags: java, spring-boot, velocity

I have a REST API based on Spring boot 1.3.3. I use Velocity only for email template.

There is no JSP/HTML view. I use exclusively RestController from Spring.

Sometimes, I get this error: "ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'error.vm' in any resource loader."
It's exclusively this vm file which is requested.

Should I disable something to my Spring Boot app to disable this error?

Comment: How is velocity included?  If you are using their starter it may include the controller translations for web pages.  What do you mean by "It's exclusively this vm file which is requested."?  Can you give more info on the conditions when this error comes up?

Comment: I don't know exactly when this error comes up. I have no other log than this and it can pop 6 times in 1second like nothing in an hour.

I use this starter pack : 
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Velocity is now deprecated in Spring Boot so we replaced it by Handlebars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Velocity is looking for this template if it has an errors so you may have a problem with a template and it trying to get the error content but cannot.  Per http://s2velocity.sandbox.seasar.org/en/error_template.html "when an error caught in a view template and rendering is forwarded to error.vm."

You can change the name of this in the property files according to the documentation.

I don't think you want to suppress these messages so you should try to catch the errors and see what the problem is.